# Is there a better way to include?

Tags: php

I decided that I wanted to use an includes file in my status success message so that I could add "extra" messages from time to time and only edit the includes file instead of having to edit the major main file all of the time.  Here is my code:

```
$successP = include("includes/usermain/successpage.php"); 

$statusMessage = "<fieldset style=\"margin-left:20px; float:left; clear:both;\"><img src=\"images/success.gif\"> <font color=\"#CC0000\" size=\"3\"><b>Success!</b></font><br>Your file, <b>". $_FILES['bFile']['name'] ."</b>, was successfully uploaded. Please use the form below if you need to upload another file. <br /> </fieldset><br />";

echo $successP;
```

This method works.  However, I was told on another forum that there was a better approach to this.  However, nothing else was said.

So my question is ... what is the best approach to achieve what I am trying to achieve here?  Or rather, is there something wrong with my current approach?

Comment: 'better' in what sense? and please consider learning css

Comment: @Dagon: She's using CSS.

Comment: @rid: Actually you can `return` from `include`s, and presumably that's what's going on here.

Comment: then she should not be using `<font` ....

Comment: I'd strongly suggest you look at a more OOP design, as suggested by Frits Van Campen.  What's happening right now is basically magic methods -- there's no way to tell by just looking at your code where things are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

`include` is like a really rudimentary function call.

If you want to do proper composition, put your classes and functions in separate files, include the ones you need and start off by initializing your application with whatever input data there is ($_GET etc.)

I can't really tell from just this how knowledgeable you are about object-oriented programming, but if you're not yet familiar with classes and functions, that's a good point to start :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure in what respect you mean by a better approach. From a functional stand point, you have four possible options for dynamic evaluation of a file's contents:

- include( 'foo.php' ) - Seen as above
- include_once( 'foo.php' ) - If foo.php already called in current template, error is thrown
- require( 'foo.php' ) - Same as include(), except fatal error is thrown if foo.php is 404
- require_once( 'foo.php' ) - The love child of include_once() and require()

You can read up more about them here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php

If you wish to suppress any errors thrown by these includes, prefix the function call with the @ (e.g. @include('foo.php'); not recommended since it hides poor coding practices.

If you provide more detail then we can give you more insight.

Comment: `include_once( 'foo.php' ) - If foo.php already called in current template, error is thrown` No, `include_once` and `require_once` silently ignore any subsequent includes for the same file. No error is thrown.